Find the index of a child in lxml
I am using Python 3.12 and lxml.
I want to find a particular tag, and I can do it with elem.find("tag"). elem is of type Element.
But I want to move child elements of this child into the parent where the child was. For that, I need the index of the child. ANd I can't find a way to find that index.
lxml's API description has the _Element.index() method, but I have no idea how to get an _Element instance from an Element instance.
Please advise how to determine that index. (Using a loop instead of find() can do that but I'd like a neater way).
EDIT: here is a sample XML element
<parent>
  <child-a/>
  <container>
     <child-b/>
     <child-c/>
  </container>
  <child-d/>
  <child-e/>
</parent>

I am writing code that finds , which is a child of  but I don't know its position in advance (there can be several of them too), and moves its children into the parent where it was, then deletes , to get this:
<parent>
  <child-a/>
  <child-b/>
  <child-c/>
  <child-d/>
  <child-e/>
</parent>

So, I can find <container> using parent.find(). But to move its children into the same place under <parent> I need to have the index of <container>, as the insert() method requires an index. For now I use this kludge:
    while True:
        index = None
        found = None
        for i in range(len(parent)):
            if parent[i].tag =="container":
                found = parent[i]
                index = i
                break
        if found is None:
            break

        offset = 0
        while len(found) > 0:
            parent.insert(index+offset,found[0])
            offset+=1
        parent.remove(found)

I do know that offset is redundant as one could just increase index, I did that for aesthetic reasons. But the loop itself is quite the kludge. Here is what I would do if Element had an index() method, but it doesn't:
    found = parent.find("container")
    while found:
        index = parent.index(found)
        offset = 0
        while len(found) > 0:
            parent.insert(index+offset,found[0])
            offset+=1
        parent.remove(found)
        found = parent.find("container")

But Element.index() does not exist; _Element.index() exists but I don't know how to access _Element.

You don’t need the index to do that, there is an insert() and append() , extend() method to do that. Please share your code and a minimal working example, include your  input xml example and what you like to get as an output.

For all I know, insert() requires an index, but I will edit the question to add a sample.

for single child you could do parent.replace(container, container.getchildren()[0]) but later you still have problem to insert other children.

@Michail Ramendik, for insert you need the position in the tag list, yes. See my answer below. For that task enumerate() could also be helpful.

You can use container.getchildren() or list(container) to get all children and use addnext() to put them (one by one) after container, and later you can remove (aready) empty container. It needs reversed() to put children in correct order.
parent = container.getparent()

#for child in reversed(container.getchildren()):
for child in reversed(container):
    container.addnext(child)

parent.remove(container)    


Full working example which I was using for tests (with some extra comments):

I used two containers without indentations - to check later methods to clean indentations.
I added child.tail = container.tail to clean some indentations.
I added ET.indent(tree) to clean all indentations.
I added reversed(container) instead of reversed(container.getchildren())
I added also container.iterchildren(reversed=True) instead of reversed(container)

html = '''
<parent>
  <child-a/>
  <container><child-b/><child-c/></container>
  <child-d/>
  <container><child-e/><child-f/></container>
  <child-g/>
</parent>
'''

import lxml.html

tree = lxml.html.fromstring(html)

for container in tree.findall('container'):
    parent = container.getparent()
    #for child in reversed(container.getchildren()):  # getchildren() - deprecated
    #for child in reversed(container):
    for child in container.iterchildren(reversed=True):
        #child.tail = None   # clean indentations  # elements in one line
        #child.tail = "\n"   # clean indentations  # next tag starts in first column
        #child.tail = container.tail   # clean indentations 
        container.addnext(child)
    parent.remove(container)    

# https://lxml.de/apidoc/lxml.etree.html#lxml.etree.indent
import lxml.etree as ET
#ET.indent(tree, space='    ')  # clean all indentations - use 4 spaces
#ET.indent(tree, space='....')  # clean all indentations - use 4 dots - looks like TOC (Table Of Contents) in book :)
ET.indent(tree)   # clean all indentations - use (default) 2 spaces

#html = lxml.html.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True).decode() 
#html = lxml.html.tostring(tree).decode() 
html = lxml.html.tostring(tree, encoding='unicode')  # not `utf-8` but `unicode` ???

print(html)

Result without child.tail = container.tail and without ET.indent(tree):
<parent>
  <child-a></child-a>
  <child-b></child-b><child-c></child-c><child-d></child-d>
  <child-e></child-e><child-f></child-f><child-g></child-g>
</parent>

Result with child.tail = container.tail or with ET.indent(tree):
<parent>
  <child-a></child-a>
  <child-b></child-b>
  <child-c></child-c>
  <child-d></child-d>
  <child-e></child-e>
  <child-f></child-f>
  <child-g></child-g>
</parent>


Doc:
addnext(),
addprevious(),
lxml.etree.indent(),
getparen(),
getchildren(),
iterchildren(reversed=True)

Thanks! My only question here is regarding for container in tree.findall('container') : will this always work correctly with multiple instances of , seeing as we are iterating over a changing object?

well, good question. Some tools for scraping (like Selenium) would make problems with this but my testing code didn't make any problem with changing objects. But maybe it need more complex example which could need to use more memory (and it would need to move objects in memory). You would have test it on your own because I don't have bigger example :)

Thanks! And I think I found a bulletproof workaround for this worry. containers = tree.findall("container") and then iterating over containers, a normal in-memory list at this point. Or is there a trap here?

I think assigning to variable works the same as using it directly in for-loop because findall() always gives list with data - it is not iterator which would need to use list(...) to get all data at once.

I think assigning to variable works the same as using it directly in for-loop because findall() always gives list with data - it is not iterator (like iterfind()) which would need to use list(...) to get all data at once.

In addition to @Furas answer, here are the steps, what also works with the built-in xml.etree.ElementTree - no need for lxml or html.
Be aware that getchildren() from lxml is deprecated since python 3.9.
For deep nested tree, a funktion definition is needed.
from lxml import etree

xml_ = """\
<parent>
  <child-a/>
  <container>
     <child-b/>
     <child-c/>
  </container>
  <child-d/>
  <child-e/>
</parent>"""

root = etree.fromstring(xml_)

# collect elements in container
container = root.findall(".//container/*")
# print([x.tag for x in container])

# position of container tag to insert
le = root.findall("./")
i = [le.index(i) for i in le if i.tag == "container"]
# print(i)

# Remove child from parent if the position is unknown
# root.find('.//container/..').remove(root.find('.//container'))
root.remove(root.find('.//container'))

# insert elements from container
for n in range(len(container)):
    root.insert(int(*i)+n, container[n])
            
etree.indent(root, space = '  ')
etree.dump(root)

Output:
<parent>
  <child-a/>
  <child-b/>
  <child-c/>
  <child-d/>
  <child-e/>
</parent>

By the way, if you need only content and not the tree by his own, there is a much easier solution with pandas to flat the structure. https://stackoverflow.com/a/78628067/12621346
As a shorter SOLUTION with XPath() ,pop() and extend():
root = etree.fromstring(xml_)

childs = root.findall(".//*")
[childs.pop(childs.index(x)) for x in childs if x.tag == "container"]

parent = etree.Element("parent")
parent.extend(childs)
    
etree.indent(parent, space='  ')
etree.dump(parent)

